# Python PIL - Cannot find reference '[' in 'None'

Tags: python, pycharm

I've been searching answers for this for the past hour and I'm feeling like any already asked question just barely misses my case.

I have been tinkering with the PIL library in Python, trying my first time to manipulate pixels, when all of a sudden a "Cannot find reference '[' in 'None'" Warning pops out. Naturally, I tried to read the IDE's warning and looked up simillar warnings online but only ended up with "missing imports" or "wrongly set interpreters".

This is the code in question:

```
from PIL import Image

with Image.open("./shoop_da_whoop.jpg") as img:
    pixel = img.load()
    width, height = img.size

    for x in range(0, width, 2):
        for y in range(0, height, 2):
            pixel[x, y] = (255, 0, 0)

    img.show()
```

The warning is right under the bracket: pixel*[*x, y] = (255, 0, 0).
I have no clue whats going on and I will gladly try every advise.

I'm running Python 3.10 on the PyCharm version 2022.1

Comment: It sounds like your IDE is warning you that `pixel` might be `None`, while you assume that the open-and-load process is going to succeed flawlessly.

Comment: The error persist, even if I add a check for ```pixels is not None```

Answer (score 4):

PyCharm relies on [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed) stubs here and there is [a mistake](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/2a0fc1b582ef84f7a82c0beb39fa617de2539d3d/stubs/Pillow/PIL/Image.pyi#L131) (or rather a missing type annotation) in them - `load()` method is declared to return `None`

```py
class Image:
    ...
    def load(self) -> None: ...
```

Comment: Problem is that the code works as intended, yet the error remains. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

There'a ticket for **PyCharm**:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-55584/Add-a-way-to-selectively-disable-third-party-package-stubs-included-in-the-bundled-Typeshed

If they implement that feature to disable **typeshed**, the return types should resolve correctly.

In my case, it was shown as error with red wavy line.
To convert it to a yellow warning, I used explicit typing.

In this example it would be:

```
pixel: PyAccess = img.load()
```